# can create a file but cannot write in it

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I am to do a file handling operation but the problem is, it can execute only up to the create file. it seems like it can't save the user's input that is to be written inside the file. I would appreciate every help i can get as i need to get it done tonight.. Thank you.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

        buff db 30      ;how many characters
        total db 0
        char db 30 dup(0)   ;for title
        com db 100 dup(0)   ;for comment
        x  db "Input your name: ", '$'
        handler dw ?
        y db "Comment your suggestion, request, feedback etc.: $"

.code
start   proc near
        mov ax,3
        int 10h

        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax

    call poop

        mov dx,offset buff      ;variable para sa input ng name ng file
        mov ah,0ah              ;BUFFERED INPUT
        int 21h

    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, total
    add bx, offset char
    mov byte ptr [bx], 0

    mov dx, offset char
    mov  ah, 3ch                ;CREATE FILE.
    mov  cx, 0
    int  21h

    mov handler, ax

    mov ah, 40h         ;write string
    mov bx, handler
    mov cx, 120         ;string length
        call poopy

        mov dx,offset buff      ;variable for input of file
        mov ah,0ah              ;BUFFERED INPUT
        int 21h

    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, total
    add bx, offset com
    mov byte ptr [bx], 0    

    mov dx, offset com  ;?
    int 21h

    mov ah,3eh          ;close file
    mov bx, handler
    int 21h

    call exit

exit: 
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
start   endp

poop    proc near
    mov dx, offset x
    mov ah,9
    int 21h 
    ret
poop endp

poopy   proc near
    mov dx, offset y
    mov ah,9
    int 21h 
    ret
poopy endp
end start
```

Comment: All uses of `int 21h` require an operation code in `AH` to specify what the operating system is supposed to do.  You never set that register for one of your calls (commented with "?" on the line above), so it could do basically ANYTHING based on what happens to be in that register at the moment.

Comment: Use a debugger to single step, and add info to make this a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

### How you write the file

> ```
> mov ah, 40h         ;write string
> mov bx, handler
> mov cx, 120         ;string length
> ```

The above lines in your code are out of place. There's nothing available to write into the newly created file yet. Moreover the snippet is incomplete and the counter is oversized (120 being more than the 100 that you could have eventually).

This is the correct place for these lines of code:

```
mov dx, offset com  ;?

mov ah, 40h         ;write string      <<<
mov bx, handler                        <<<
mov cx, 100                            <<<

int 21h

mov ah,3eh          ;close file
mov bx, handler
int 21h
```

Perhaps it would be better to only write in the file the bytes that you actually got from inputting?
Then write

```
mov dx, offset com
mov ch, 0
mov cl, total
mov bx, handler
mov ah, 40h         ;Write file
int 21h
```

---

### How you get the input

> ```
> buff db 30      ;how many characters
> total db 0
> char db 30 dup(0)   ;for title
> com db 100 dup(0)   ;for comment
> ```

You're using the DOS buffered input twice, but there's a conflict with the definitions.

- Either use 2 separate and complete definitions:

  ```
  buff1  db 30          ;how many characters
  total1 db 0
  char   db 30 dup(0)   ;for title

  buff2  db 100         ;how many characters
  total2 db 0
  com    db 100 dup(0)  ;for comment
  ```
- Or else re-use a single definition that can suit the largest needs:

  ```
  buff   db 100         ;how many characters
  total  db 0
  buf    db 100 dup(0)  ;for title or comment
  ```

I prefer the second methode, but make sure to zero *total* before asking another input. You might also want to reduce the size if less input is required:

```
mov buff, 30           ;Reduce size for name input
mov total, 0
mov dx, offset buff
mov ah, 0Ah            ;BUFFERED INPUT
int 21h
...
mov buff, 100          ;Full size for contents input
mov total, 0
mov dx, offset buff
mov ah, 0Ah            ;BUFFERED INPUT
int 21h
```